# Is there any way to know the size of what will be printed to standard output in C++?

Tags: c++

For example, if I use the following:

```
cout << "hello world";
```

Is there any way to know the size of what's being printed to stdout?

Comment: In what units? Characters, pixels, something else?

Comment: This seems like an XY-problem. Why do you need to know? Not all types implement a "size", and the actual data can be serialized by providing a `operator<<` overload, which is done by the standard library for strings.

Comment: You can do it with two steps, construct a string from the data, measure it, 
 do whatever you need to do with that length, then print it. An example would be you want to arrange variable length data into columns but you don't know how side the column needs to be. You'll need to find the longest item in each column before you decide their size. You might try explaining your use case for better advice.

Comment: byte is the unit by default

Comment: I apologize because I think I asked the wrong question. What I actually meant is "is there anyway to know the current number of bytes printed to the stdout?".  Should I eliminate the thread and ask a new question or edit this thread?. It looks like this thread makes a lot of sense for a lot of people, so I think I will leave it as it is.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) for this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::stringstream ss;
  int a = 3;
  ss<<"Hello, world! "<<a<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Size was: "<<ss.str().size()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<ss.str()<<std::endl;
}
```

The above returns 16: 14 character for "Hello, world!", 1 character for the contents of the variable `a`, and one character from `std::endl`.

Comment: this could be an overkill if you output just a single ascii string as in your example without `endl`. you can just measure its length with `strlen` or `string.length()`

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a standard way to determine how much bytes will be written to the standard output before writing it.

What you could do is, write it to an `ostringstream` and get the size of the stream. This doubles the work, but gives you a standard generic way to determine how many bytes will an object take when written to a stream:

```
template <class T>
std::size_t stream_len(const T& t)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << t;
    return oss.tellp();
}
```

Here is a demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3de664b4059250ae

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old school C style way that is still valid C++ as well as modern C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // C style but still valid c++
    std::cout << "C style but still valid C++\n";
    char phrase[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd' }; 
    char phrase2[] = { "hello world" };

    // Adding 1 for the new line character.
    std::cout << "size of phrase[] in bytes = " 
              << sizeof(phrase) 
              << " + 1 for newline giving total of " 
              << sizeof(phrase) + 1 
              << " total bytes\n"; // Not Null terminated

    std::cout << "size of phrase2[] in bytes = " 
              << sizeof(phrase2) 
              << " + 1 for newline giving total of " 
              << sizeof(phrase2) + 1 
              << " total bytes\n";  // Null terminated

    // Or you can do it more c++ style
    std::cout << "\nC++ style\n";
    // Also adding one for newline character and this string is not null terminated
    std::cout << "size of string in bytes = " 
              << std::string("hello world").size() 
              << " + 1 for newline giving a total of " 
              << std::string("hello world").size() + 1 
              << " total bytes\n";

    std::cout << "Press any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

Since each character in C/C++ is 1 byte; all you need is the count of characters including special characters such as space, null terminator, newline etc. That is why there is a `sizeof( Type ) operator` in C/C++.

**Output**

```
C style but still valid C++
size of phrase[] in bytes = 11 + 1 for newline giving total of 12 total bytes
size of phrase2[] in bytes = 12 + 1 for newline giving total of 13 total bytes

C++ style
size of string in bytes = 11 + 1 for newline giving a total of 12 total bytes
Press any key and enter to quit.
```

Now this will only give you the size of the output before you send it to the `ostream's` `cout` object. This also doesn't reflect the added characters of text that is describing this output.

As others have stated you can use `stringstream` to concatenate a bunch of strings, characters and other data types into the `stringstream` object with the `insertion operator <<` and then have the `stream's` member function give you the size in `bytes`.

It works in the same manner as `std::string( ... ).size()`.